# UBS-Stick with Arch is no longer bootable after Win8 has been booted

Tags: arch-linux, windows

I bought an Acer Aspire S7 and wanted to try an Arch Installation on an USB-Stick. I followed the [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide). I also set up disk encryption using dm-crypt+LUKS es described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_Entire_System).

After everything was done, I rebooted and it worked just fine. However, I then booted Win8 and when I tried booting Arch again, it failed. The USB-key was no longer recognized as bootable.

By reinstalling Grub, I can make the USB-key bootable again, but it only works as long as I don't boot Win8. Obviously, when booting Windows, the USB-key is not connected, so its data cannot be modified by the Windows boot process. It seems, installing Grub not only writes to the USB-Key but also configures something on the notebooks hdd. Something that is undone by booting Windows.

Edit: I installed Arch from another live-usb-stick (which I can boot reliably) and followed parts 1 and 2 of the Beginners guide. Utill just before "post-intallation". When I reinstall grub I open the encrypted partition, mount root and /boot, arch-chroot into /mnt and reinstall via

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck
```

I then exit, umount, close the encrypted partition and reboot. Then, booting from this stick works as long as Win8 is not booted.

Comment: You should fill in some ambiguities here.  *"After everything was done"* -> you mean all 3 steps in that guide?  How are you then reinstalling grub if the stick won't boot?  What's the medium you were installing from?  The more details you provide the more likely someone can quickly spot the problem.